# mysql allows access with every password in terminal but not in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, ubuntu-16.04

Ubutnu 16.04 , mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper .

It's a droplet on DigitalOcean, I have fresh install mysql and after I have use

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

i have set a password, remove anonymous user and try both of remove or not root remote login

the problem is: mysql give me access with every password on `$ mysql -u root -p` or simply with `$ mysql` without password on the terminal, but in Laravel I can't login with or without password

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: select * from`prodotti`)`

1) I have try to create a new user

`CREATE USER ‘username’@‘localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

2) i have try ( --skip-grant-tables ) for create new user but I don't know why I get the terminal stucked

3) i have try to remove and reinstall mysql ...

I don't know where I'm wrong!

Comment: Can you please tell what you get when you run this command SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;

Comment: Also make sure you have added database,  username and password in .env file

Comment: i have solve using:

    
    $ mysql_secure_installation

I haven't activated the plugin for check password strenght, and after acconsent to all ...

Create the user without set the password

        
    $ mysql    
    > CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost';

after give the privilege and set the password

    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databaseName.* To 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';